# Concerns about the display of a 2015 MBP being up for a while

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I was attempting to update my 2015 MacBook Pro to macOS Big Sur 11.4 last night, but due to the low download speeds I have on my home router, I had to leave it up for about 12 hours (and it still didn't update). I'm wondering if that hurt the display (or the computer, for that matter) at all. It was plugged in and awake at auto-adjusting brightness for about 11.5-12 hours. Does this harm the Retina display (13in) in any way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this does not harm your Mac in any way.

Your display will most likely outlast most other components of your MacBook. Something even more likely is that performance will drop so you decide to get a new machine within the next five years.

Only excessive use in very bad conditions (very humid, very hot,...) can shorten a Macs/computers lifetime drastically but usually your battery will be the first to be replaced, not your display.